# How to add a custom section to the User Edit Screen in Liferay?

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-aui, liferay-ide

I want to customize the User-Edit page in Liferay 6.2.

First of all I wanted to add a new section to the bar on the right of the user edit screen (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rnilo.png). I have realized this with properties like

> users.form.add.main=customportlet

When i click on the new created section it opens a blank page. How can I add content here (the data will be stored on separate tables)?

I know that i can create custom fields simply through the configurations but i would like to realize it on this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is a [hook](https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/6-2/customizing-liferay-portal).

You use the file `WEB-INF/liferay-hook.xml` as deployment descriptor:

```
<!DOCTYPE hook PUBLIC "-//Liferay//DTD Hook 6.2.0//EN" 
          "http://www.liferay.com/dtd/liferay-hook_6_2_0.dtd">
<hook>
    <portal-properties>portal.properties</portal-properties>
    <language-properties>Language.properties</language-properties>
    <custom-jsp-dir>/WEB-INF/custom_jsps</custom-jsp-dir>
</hook>
```

And you define your additional section in the file `WEB-INF/classes/portal.properties`:

```
# users.form.add.main is for the creation of a user only 
# I guess you mean the user edit screen:
users.form.update.main=my-section
```

Implement your section as JSP file in `WEB-INF/custom_jsps/html/portlet/users_admin/user/my-section.jsp`:

```
<%@include file="/html/portlet/users_admin/init.jsp" %>

<h3><liferay-ui:message key="my-section" /></h3>
<%-- Implement your section --%>
```

And label your section in `WEB-INF/classes/Language.properties`:

```
my-section = My Section
```

Thats it.

Comment: Hi Tobias, thank you for your answer. How can i now add the data to my own database table? If it is possible I want to use a portlet:actionURL. I have now defined for examle an aui:input in a aui:fieldset. For Example: <aui:input label="Question 1?" name="var1"></aui:input>. But it shows me no text box to enter the value because var1 is not defined in the database.

Comment: Maybe you should first try to develop your own [JSP Portlet](https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/6-1/writing-the-my-greeting-portlet) with the desired functions before starting to extend Liferays existing portlets. It helps to understand whats going on under the hood in a hook ;-) - The tutorial about [Overriding and Adding Struts Actions](https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/6-1/overriding-and-adding-struts-actions) may help as well.

Comment: Thank you four your answer. Yes you are right. I have read the chapters to understand the functionality. I tried with overriding the Struts actions like "/users_admin/edit_user" but it didnt work. I tried it also with "shared plugin". I now need this functionality :(

Comment: You should really try to understand how Liferay portlets are working - as your section will be a part of it. Have a look at `[ROOT]/html/portlet/users_admin/user/details.jsp` for an example of another section and try to read more Liferays tutorials, e.g. [Writing a Data-Driven Application](https://dev.liferay.com/develop/learning-paths/-/knowledge_base/6-2/writing-a-data-driven-application). Its not a trivial task and I feel we are getting a little bit off-topic here...